# Корова и говядина

Tags: этимология

Почему животное называется корова (или бык), а мясо — говядина?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Говядина образовано от устаревшего на сей день слова  говядо - крупный рогатый скот. (У Даля к говядо относятся корова,  бык и  вол)

Answer (score 0):

Корова произошла от ПИЕ ***ceru̯a̯*** "рогатая".

Говятина произошла от ПИЕ ***ğeo̯us***, "корова".